# How to set Design for all Screen in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've develop an application for my project. In that I don't know how to set layout in all screen. If I change another screen that default screen is also changes. Here is my code. So how can I set layout in all screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/custom_bg">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativemail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/imageid"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="180dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
     android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"        
            android:background="@drawable/upload_photo" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageid"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/galary_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/camera"
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cameraxml" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center" >
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/galary"
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"        
                            android:background="@drawable/galeryxml" />  
        </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/saveid"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="65dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/buttonid"
     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:background="@drawable/save_bg"
     android:gravity="center" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/savexml"/>
     </LinearLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/saveid"
     android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="84dp" >

     <ToggleButton
         android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"

         android:background="@drawable/chapxml" />
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: avoid use of hardcoded values of height and width,use wrap_content or match_parent.and in case of you have to put hardcoded values then create dimens for different devices into values/dimens.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `dp`, `sp`, `px` and other hard values you have to use `match_parent` and `wrap_content`. Those are dynamic values that change by screen width, height and dpi.

Comment: @user3755817 I don't know how it should look like exactly, just play with the dynamic values and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using fragments and only change the specific views that you need to change across activities but an easier option would be to [re-use layout using](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) .

Create a layout with all those views and use `<merge>` tag to enclose them. Then create different layout files(xml) for different activities and use `<include>` as described in the link.